# how to fix these strange gaps?

Tags: longtable, texlive, center, gap

I can't fix words that run out...I also need everything to be there centered like on this table:
[image: https://www.mindev.gov.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Request-for-Quotation-RFQ-No.-RFQ-CO-115182-DAVS.pdf]
My code:

```
    \documentclass[13pt, a4paper, twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=20mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=10mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{14}{18}\selectfont}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{22mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{. }
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{2mm}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{8mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecaftersnum}{. }
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{2mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\cftdotfill{1}}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{5mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{12mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecaftersnum}{. }
\renewcommand{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\cftdotfill{1}}

\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{15mm}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Rys. }
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{. }
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{1}}

\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{0mm}
\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{15mm}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Tab. }
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{. }
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{1}}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\def\verbarg{{\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont\makebox[7mm]{\arabic{VerbboxLineNo}}}\hspace{12mm}}

\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{Alg.}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\renewcommand\thesection{Rozdział \Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[font=bf, labelfont=bf, belowskip=-0mm]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Rys., labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tab.,  labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{margin=0pt, font=bf, labelsep=period}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font=bf, labelsep=period}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE, LO]{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{}
\fancyhead[RE, LO]{}
}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Kod.}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black},
numbersep=5pt,
showspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
keepspaces=true,
tabsize=2,
xleftmargin=20pt,
framexleftmargin=20pt,
captionpos=tc,
backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
keywordstyle=\color{black},
inputencoding=utf8
}




\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|p{.23\textwidth}|cc|cc|p{.17\textwidth}|}  
        \caption{Lista wybranych predefiniowanych reguł możliwych do zautomatyzowania}
        \label{tab1}
        \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ID} & NAZWA & \multicolumn{2}{p{.1\textwidth}|}{WYMAGANIA NATO}       & \multicolumn{2}{p{.1\textwidth}|}{WYMAGANIA KRAJOWE}    & UWAGI\\ \cline{3-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                    &                        & \multicolumn{1}{p{.001\textwidth}|}{NC/  NS/ CTS} & NU/NR  & \multicolumn{1}{p{.003\textwidth}|}{NC/ \par NS/ \par CTS} & NU/NR &                        \\ \hline
        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%PSW%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        PSW3-1& Ochrona\hspace{0.1cm}przed oprogramowaniem typu malware jest wdrażane w CIS wykorzystując podejście wielowarstwowe.& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M}&M& Np. Serwery,\hspace{0.1cm}punkty\hspace{0.1cm}końcowe, \hspace{0.1cm}serwery proxy,\hspace{0.1cm}ochrona poczty e-mail itd. Ochronna powinna obejmować oprogramowanie antywirusowe, oprogramowanie antyszpiegowskie, anty-phishing. Wbudowana ochrona przez złośliwym oprogramowaniem jest autoryzowana przez SAA lub wyłączona.       
        \\ \hline
        PSW3-2                                        & Wykorzystywana jest różnorodność anty-malware.                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   &  M  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   &M  & Stosowane są różne rodzaje ochrony przez złośliwym oprogramowaniem. Różnorodność powinna obejmować różne silniki lub bazy sygnatur.                     \\ \hline
        PSW3-4                                        & Aktualizacje przed złośliwym oprogramowaniem są wrdażane w ciągu 24 godzin                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   &    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   &M {\large /} M     & Uchylenie od tego harmonogramu jest uzgadniane z SAA, bądź lokalnym funkcjonariuszem bezpieczeństwa CIS.                 \\ \hline
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%POS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        POS2-2                                         & Zastosowanie wirtualizacji zasobów(hypervisor) typu 2 powinien być zatwierdzony przez SAA i jest dozwolony dla specjalnych CIS w wyjątkowych celach. Dostęp techniczny jest możliwy jedynie przez specjalnie upoważniony personel             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & Hypervisor typu 2 może zostać użyty do ominięcia środków bezpieczeństwa, dlatego musi być ograniczony i kontrolowany.
        
        \\ \hline
        POS6-1                                         &Ochrona E-mail przed spamem, phishing’iem i oprogramowaniem typu malware jest zapewniona za pomocą bramy sieciowej.& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   & M    & Mówiąc inaczej jest zapewnione oprogramowanie filtrowania treści wiadomości. 
        \\ \hline
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%CS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
        
        CS6-4                                         &Zapobieganie jest korzystanie z nieautoryzowanych wymiennych nośników pamięci & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & Ma to na celu zapobiec wprowadzenia złośliwego oprogramowania, bądź przypadkowej utracie danych ewentualnie ich kradzieży. Przykładowymi nośnikami pamięci są: Płyty CD, DVD, dyskietki, pamięć USB     \\ \hline        
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%IAM%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        
        
        IAM3-6                                         & Aplikacja uwierzytelniająca jest ukrywana podczas procesu uwierzytelniania             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & Hasło zostaje przysłonięte gwiazdkami.
        Jeśli została wprowadzona niepoprawna nazwa użytkownika, wtedy użytkownik nie zostaje o tym poinformowany.                
        \\ \hline
        
        IAM4-1                                         & Zasady tworzenia haseł wymagają od użytkowników \par wybrania hasła o długości co najmniej 12 znaków, przy użyciu co najmniej  3 z 4 typów znaków klawiatury.              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   & R    & Typy znaków na klawiaturze: wielkie litery, małe litery, cyfry i znaki specjalne. \par W przypadku innych parametrów siły hasła, organ zajmujący się akredytacją bezpieczeństwa może zatwierdźić te zmiany.              \\ \hline
        
        IAM4-2                                         & Powszechnie używane hasła i podciągi są blokowane za pomocą czarnych list, które zawierają owe hasła.                   & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & Czarna lista może obejmować hasła takie jak: \par -Wzorce klawiatury (np. „zaq12wsx” lub „qwertyuiop”) \par - Hasła uzyskane z poprzednich naruszeń danych( np. baza haseł Rockyou) \par -Powtarzające się lub sekwencyjne znaki (np. „aaaaaaaa” lub „1234abcd”)\\ \hline
        
        IAM4-4                                         & Hasła są ważne od 1 roku do lat 3, jeśli CIS przetwarza informacje typu NC/NS/CTS. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & \large{N/A}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   & \large{N/A}    & Okres ważności hasła jest uzgadniany przez CISOA, CISP i SAA. Dolny limit wygaśnięcia hasła jest wymuszany, ponieważ krótsze okresy wygaśnięcia hasła zapewniają niepożądaną zachętę dla użytkowników do ponownego wykorzystywania słabszych haseł. \\ \hline
        IAM4-5                                         & Hasła są ważne od 1 roku do lat 2, jeśli CIS przetwarza informacje typu NU/NR. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large{N/A}}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\large{N/A}}   & R   & Okres ważności hasła jest uzgadniany przez CISOA, CISP i SAA. Dolny limit wygaśnięcia hasła jest wymuszany, ponieważ krótsze okresy wygaśnięcia hasła zapewniają niepożądaną zachętę dla użytkowników do ponownego wykorzystywania słabszych haseł. \\ \hline
        
        
        IAM4-6                                      & Zabronione jest ponowne użycie hasła przez 10 pokoleń (Użytkownicy nie mogą ponownie użyć swoich 10 ostatnich haseł w systemie).                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}   & M    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{R}   & R    & Ograniczenie to uniemożliwia użytkownikowi do starego hasła.                \\ \hline
        
        IAM4-8                                      & CIS przechowuje tylko kryptograficznie chronione hasła. Do haszowania hasła jest wykorzystywana unikalna i losowa sól. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}&M & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}&M& Sól nie musi być tajemnicą\\ \hline
        IAM8-1                                      & CIS automatycznie tworzy logi utworzenia, modyfikacji, włączenia, wyłączenia, podniesienia uprawnień i usuwania konta. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}&M & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}&M&\\ \hline
        IAM8-4                                      & Nieaktywne konta są wyłączone w ciągu
        90 dni. & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}&M & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{M}&M&\\ \hline
        
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
    

\end{document}
```

And my table:
[image]
I want this same table like on the first pciture...

Comment: Welcome. // Please prepare your code so we can copy, compile and still see your problem. // Please add a screenshot from the linked document, if that's relevant. Links may be gone in a year or two while this place will still be available ...

Comment: in the "paragraph" cells, add `\raggedright`.

Comment: I added picture and I have reedited code

Comment: @barbarabeeton what do you mean? Paragraph cells?

Comment: The text in the second and last columns should be ragged right, so all extra space goes at the end of each line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton IT WORKS. THANK YOU <3

Comment: Glad to be of help.  This is a very basic concept in typesetting.  I am attempting to put together a list of TeX/general typesetting basics, and will definitely include this.